# Plotting data with a second x axis of ticks for fractionated data

Tags: ticks, intervals, frame

I have a dataset which is a list of 37,473 {x,y} pairs, in the format of {{0,1},{1,2},{2,3} ... }. It is an elution profile where the x value is mL and the y value is absorbance. Lets call an example dataset

`testset={{0,0},{1,2},{2,4},{3,6},{4,5},{5,2},{6,15},{7,3},{8,0},{9,0.3},{10,0}}`.

I can execute

`ListLinePlot[testset, Frame->True, FrameLabel->{"Elution Volume (mL)","Absorbance at 280nm"}]`

to give the trace of absorbance changes throughout the  elution off of the chromatographic system, however the elution is fractionated at a fixed 5 mL interval, meaning we could also display this as a relationship of fraction and absorbance.

How can I add a second x axis showing the fractions, with the ticks counting up from 1 until the end of the chromatographic separation at 5 mL increments?
Alternately, how can I only have ticks every 5 mL counting up from one? (for `testset`, this would mean that the x axes would be 1-10 for the mL and 1-2 for the two fractions)

**Important to note**--the actual mL values (x in the {x,y} lists in the list `testset`) are not integers, the mL recordings are every ~0.007931 mL)

Comment: What ticks would be on the secondary axis? In this case only 2 ticks at 5 and 10ml?

Comment: The two ticks would indeed be 1, at 5 mL, and 2, at 10 mL, since fraction 1 is from 0-5 mL, and fraction 2 is the next 5 mL, from 5-10 mL.

Comment: A hand-drawn picture, in this case, would be worth a thousand comments.